# Rails paper_trail with Active Storage causing duplicate versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, paper-trail-gem

I'm using the [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) gem and only want versions to be created when one attribute `version_number` is changed. I set up the model with the following line:

```
has_paper_trail only: [:version_number]
```

Everything was working fine until I added an Active Storage image attribute to the same model. In the model I simply added the following:

```
has_many_attached :image
```

The problem now is when I attach a new `image` to this model, a new version is cerated. The version's `object_changes` column in the database is `[null]` which is expected but also interesting because why would paper_trail be versioning when there are no object_changes.

I tried a few things, none of which worked. I tried explicitly excluding the `updated_at` and `image` attributes from `has_paper_trail`, as they appear to be the only actual changes to my model when attaching an image. I would expect the `only` to filter those out anyway.

Has anyone else had this problem? I would actually like to version the image uploads if that's possible, but I definitely do not want these duplicated versions as it causes a lot of issues in general.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same. The work around I used was PaperTrail.request

```
PaperTrail.request.disable_model(Banana)
# Attach code record.attach(image)
PaperTrail.request.enable_model(Banana) # If you need to enable it again
```

Looking forward to solving the problem on the model itself

hope this helps you

PaperTrail.request info: https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#per-class

Answer (score 2):

`ActiveStorage` calls `touch` on a record when it creates an attachment for it. Doing this saves the current time to `updated_at` on the record.

The easiest thing to do, if you're not using `touch` in other ways for which you want PaperTrail versions, is to [choose which lifecycle events to track](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#2a-choosing-lifecycle-events-to-monitor) and exclude `touch`.

E.g.

```
has_paper_trail on: [:update]
```

I actually used the accepted answer until I ran into situations where `ActiveStorage` calls `touch` after a transaction commit, which made things get messy.